# Extract value from nested json in terraform

Tags: json, dictionary, terraform

In terraform I have an external data source

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = [ 
    "some_program_generating_json"
  ]
}
```

`some_program_generating_json` produces the following output:

```
{
    "dict1": {
        "key1": "value1"
    },
    "dict2": {
        "key1": "value2"
    }
}
```

How can I extract the value of `[dict1][key1]` from that data source and assign it to some local?

lets say:

```
locals {
  extracted_value = ???
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it, and had no problems using `[dict1][key1]` notation. This is the example I used.

**script file (test.sh)**

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# from https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13991#issuecomment-526869879
printf '{"base64_encoded":"%s"}\n' $(echo '{"dict1": {"key1": "value1"}, "dict2": {"key1": "value2"}}' | base64 -w 0)
```

**main.tf**

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = [ 
    "${path.module}/scripts/test.sh"
  ]
}

locals {
  json_value = jsondecode(base64decode(data.external.example.result["base64_encoded"]))
  
  dict1_key1 = local.json_value["dict1"]["key1"] 
}

output "result" {
  value = local.dict1_key1
}
```

The output was:

```
result = value1
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I figured it out. I had to convert values of dict1 and dict2 to strings:

```
{
    "dict1": "{\"key1\": \"value1\"}",
    "dict2": "{\"key1\": \"value2\"}"
}
```

and then use jsondecode on them. I.e.

```
locals {
  key = "dict1"
  extracted_dict = jsondecode("${data.external.example.result[local.key]}")
  extracted_value = local.extracted_dict["key1"]
}
```